# Removing a links from a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a question regarding jQuery, I want to remove the following from the an object ($website) that stores the

```
 $website.html().remove('a');

 $website.html() returns = egg street eggland eg1 <a href="random">
                                                       <img src=""></img>
                                                  </a>
```

How would I remove a element and its contents ?

I have tried

```
$website.remove('a');
```

But this doesn't seem to remove anything..

Please could you point me in the right direction if I am doing this completely wrong..

Thank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a', $website).remove(); // P00F
```

Basically finds all anchor tags withing `$website` and removes them.

---

#### Reverse (based on comment below by OP):

```
$($website.children()).not('a').remove(); // P00F
```

Basically finds all things in `$website` that are **not** anchor tags and removes them.

Comment: @jondavidjohn :-P you know you like it ^_^

Comment: Alternatively, `$website.find('a').remove();`, which is how the context selector gets run behind the scenes.

Comment: Is there a way of doing the inverse of this and returning the stuff that isn't inside of the alink ?

Comment: What do you mean with "returning the stuff that isn't inside of the alink"?

Comment: @sausageRolls ummm he was asking a question, not making a statement. see my update....

Comment: Thanks for the help Neal. The example above returns an empty string.. All the child elements from the html e.g. asdasd<a href=""></a>I want the href and all child elements to be removed. Sorry if I sounded rude, have been coding all day/night

Comment: @sausageRolls none of these return **any** string. again **WHAT** are you trying to do....?

Comment: Wow sorry for the hassle got it working with the top line of code (Must have done it wrong originally).. Thanks a lot Neal, enjoy your holidays